# Hide icons on windows 8 lock screen

Tags: windows-8, lock-screen

Is there a way to hide the battery and network (wifi bar) indicators on the windows 8 lock screen?
I've already figured out how to hide the clock and date through a registry tweak, but I haven't worked out how to do the same with the icons.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

1. Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to open the Run dialog, type `gpedit.msc`, and click/tap on **OK**.
2. In the left pane, click/tap on ***Computer Configuration***, then ***Administrative Templates***, then ***System***, and open ***Logon***.
3. In the right pane of Logon, double click/tap on ***Do not display network selection UI***.
4. Select ***Enable*** and click ***OK***.
5. Finished! The WiFi icon should now be hidden from the lock screen.

Comment: tanx "sammyg" for edit my answer .